# Authorization issue in netsuite using oauth

Tags: authentication, oauth, netsuite, provisioning

I am working on Netsuite and I'm new to it, so I need help. After creating roles and assigning a user to that specific role, I want to assign them to an application created using the integration record. When I wanted to create an access token, after selecting the application in the application name drop down, I am not finding any users or roles in the user drop down box and the role drop down box:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/cNq6u.jpg]

This is where I am facing the problem. So I need a solution to select users in the drop down box.

Comment: I'm having the same exact problem. I AM able to select the user if I use the search tools, but the role selection remains empty. I have triple checked the role's settings, and that my user is associated with the role. I can;t seem to find any definitive reason for why I can't see it though.

Answer (score 1):

This link tells you all you need to know about setting up TBA and the correct basic permissions needed: 
[Token Based Authentication](http://mikebian.co/using-netsuites-token-based-authentication-with-suitetalk/)

Your user needs to have a role assigned to it with the following basic permissions:

- User Access Token: Full
- Access Token Management: Full
- Web Services: Full

Once this role has been assigned to your user, the user will be available for selection when creating a token.

Answer (score 0):

Go to the role you have setup for this OAuth and click Permissions tab > Setup and make sure User Access Tokens permission is there.

Comment: yes i did that. but still the same. i am not getting any user or role in the dropdown. i think i hav to add user and roles to the application "My App for TBA". but i dont know how.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the docs for setting up TBA roles.  Maybe you are missing one of the permissions?

[Getting Started with Token-based Authentication](https://system.na1.netsuite.com/app/help/helpcenter.nl?fid=section_4247337262.html)